Upgrading database instance for MongoDB 4.2 to 4.4 requires legacy MongoDB on Macosx
I'm running MongoDB within a ten year old node app, and in the process of upgrading node had to upgrade MongoDB. For some time, I have been using MongoDB community 4.4 to run the database, but in the process of upgrading to MongoDB community 7 (the latest) I got this error in the output log when I tried to run mongod through "brew services restart mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@4.4:"

"This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier."

I have reinstalled 4.4: the newly installed version gives this error and fails, but the older 4.4 actually worked. (Curiously -- trying to run mongodb/brew/mongodb-community I get no error messages at all, no output to the log file, but nothing works).
Several questions:

Why does 4.4 not work now, when it did earlier? It appears I now have 4.4.29, as a result of the reinstallation. How can I go back to an earlier version?
Why does mongodb/brew/mongodb-community give no output to the logfile, appears to succeed but actually fails?
Is there a way of loading and running 4.2? Brew does not support anything before 4.4, it seems. Nor does there seem to be any way of installing and running mongodb 4.2 from the mongo site.


You should be able to download old MongoDB from Archived Releases. Legacy documentation you find at Legacy Documentation or check https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x-tarball/

You cannot upgrade directly from version 4.4 to 7.0. You must upgrade step-by-step to 5.0 -> 6.0 -> 7.0. See Upgrade Version Path
